# How to get username part from example.com/username/gallery in case of ArchiveIndexView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Currenly I can get a gallery of currently logged in user via any urls as

```
example.com/user/gallery
example.com/user123/gallery
example.com/312any-thing/gallery
```

This is not what I want. What I want is to check first, if user exists, and then provide required gallery via `ArchiveIndexView`.

How can I get the `username` part of example.com/`username`/gallery in `ArchiveIndexView` class in order to implement

```
user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, slug=username)
```

?

```
# project urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_user')),
]

# app.urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name='profiles_home'),
    url(r'^gallery/$', views.ProfileGalleryArchiveIndexView.as_view(), name='profiles_gallery'),
]

# app.views
class ProfileGalleryDateView(object):
    date_field = 'date_added'
    allow_empty = True

class ProfileGalleryArchiveIndexView(ProfileGalleryDateView, ArchiveIndexView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user  # here I want to get username from url
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, slug=username)
        return Gallery.objects.filter(galleryextended__user=user).is_public()
```

I tried to get `username` from url using:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=kwargs['object'].pk)
```

but `get_queryset` executes earlier than `get_context_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL captures the username as `slug`, so you can get it from `self.kwargs['slug']`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. So easy. I will be able to accept your answer in 7 mins. Can you tell me where can I read about all attributes, which Class Based View has, except print(self.__dict__)? I can not find this info in docs.

Comment: This is actually explained in the docs about [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering). For more comprehensive API documentation though see ccbv.co.uk.